# why do we use autocomplete={ value other than on/off } in html?

Tags: html, autocomplete

can anyone tell me why we need to use values of autocomplete other than on/off (like given-name, family-name, new-password,etc.) because i found out that form will be autofilled only when name attribute form exactly matches perviously stored value having same name attribute (e.g. if my form has name="fname" than autocomplete only work when contains previously stored data in which fname="naresh" and it will suggest naresh) also if name attribute not present id attribute should be same. this will happen when autocomplete=on and works same if autocomplete=other_value_except_off then why we use these values (given-name,etc.).

i have created two files input1.html and input2.html. autocomplete only works if name attributes are same no effect of autocomplete -
input1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <label for="firstname">first name: </label><input type="text" id="firstname" name="fname" autocomplete="given-name">
    <br>
    <label for="lastname">last name: </label><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lname" autocomplete="family-name">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

input2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <label for="firstname">first name: </label><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"
      autocomplete="given-name">
    <br>
    <label for="lastname">last name: </label><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"
      autocomplete="family-name">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

here if i filled form in input1.html and then open input2.html - no suggetions but if i changed name of input2.html to fname and lname then i will suggestions. what is the role of autocomplete here. i better use autocomplete=on then why we need other values
i am using this in google chrome

Comment: It is a hint to the browser as to what data it can autofill. For example, if your user hs an address associated with it, the browsers knows that field could be autofilled with an address and it does not need to "guess" what data goes there. Usually, when you fill in a full form, it will be able to just plonk all data in and you can click next. No more than a hint, and browsers are _not required_ to actually do this.

Comment: then why my seccond file not showing me suggesions

Comment: I think most of this is in the spec, but browsers haven't gotten around to implementing it.